# invalid command-line parameter: dns-server

Tags: android

I am developing android app.

When i run this app, i finds message on console that:

```
[2013-09-05 15:12:31 - Emulator] invalid command-line parameter: dns-server.
[2013-09-05 15:12:31 - Emulator] Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.
[2013-09-05 15:12:31 - Emulator] please use -help for more information
```

I searched on SO for this error and i done :

Windows - Preferances - pathcheck

There was no blank space in SDK address.

(Besides that i again pasted address in it)

Its as follows:

[image]

Its again showing me that text in console and app is not running.

Please help me.

Comment: does your computer has 2 graphic cards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is not in the path(spaces)and you only have one graphic card you should delete your Virtual Devices and wipe it from the computer and create a new one.

Let me know if it helped :)

Comment: awesome :) have a great day Navat!

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is that nothing...You should try to remove the old Emulator and create a new Emulator but with new Name...